# VimL: capture output of `exec` command, inside a variable is possible?

Tags: vim

I have some bash scripts and I need to retrieve them output from a Vim script. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To execute an external command and capture its output in a Vim variable, use `system()`:

```
:let hostname = system('hostname')
```

The command is invoked through the configured `'shell'`; as long as your Bash script has a proper *shebang* line (`#!/bin/bash`), everything should be fine.

If you eventually want to insert the output into the current buffer, you can alternatively use `:read !{cmd}` directly:

```
:read !hostname
```

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative approach, note that the default signature of the `let` statement is:

```
let {var} = {expr}
```

where the right hand side must be an *expression*. This means that  `let` cannot capture the output of an `execute` *command*. In other words, trying:

```
let {var} = {cmd}
```

will produce an error. A workaround is to use the `redir` command, which has the following syntax:

```
redir => {var}
{cmd}
redir end
```

Let's see how it works in practice. First trying:

```
let somevar = echo "The current locale settings are: " . v:lang
```

returns the error **E15: Invalid expression**. Now with:

```
redir => somevar
echo "The current locale settings are: " . v:lang
redir end
```

the error is gone and the variable was successfully allocated, which  is verified by printing its value:

```
echo somevar
```

with output:

```
The current locale settings are: en_US.UTF-8
```